# How to clear Amazon CloudFront Cache completely?

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I made some changes to my origin server which now serves different data from same url.

I tried to clear my cache completely by doing the following invalidation in CF UI:

[image]

But this didn't work. How can I wipe off completely the Amazon CloudFront cache's in one go?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

CloudFront does now support wildcard or full distribution invalidation.  You will need do do one of the followng.

- Invalidate each object that has changed
- Invalidate /*
- Version your objects so that they are considered new (Ie rename or querystring)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-console

Answer (score 20):

You need to use `/*` instead of `/`.

Also, if you need to do this frequently, you can do it using the AWS CLI.

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=YOUR_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
```

**Edit**: thanks to [@speckledcarp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287328/how-to-clear-amazon-cloudfront-cache-completely/40577276#comment75586472_40577276), you need to use `"/*"` (with quotes) when using the CLI.

Comment: I had to put quotes around the wildcard path in the command line

Comment: @speckledcarp, did you mean using `"/*"`? Using `/*` worked for me, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Without the quotes, it grabs a list of the files in your current directory, and sends them as separate invalidation paths (ie - the wildcard is evaluated locally). I was running the command from a different folder, so it didn't work until I used `"/*"`

Comment: @speckledcarp I had to use this command again, and you're right! The quotes are really necessary when using the CLI. Thanks!

Comment: Exists a method where I can get the ID Distribution of each domain ?

Comment: Didn't need to do anything to set preview.cloudfront ... just worked fine

Comment: @KayaToast, thank you. I've updated the answer. This one was posted 3 years ago and was outdated

Answer (score 1):

According to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) you need to use /* instead of /