# Angular index.html refreshed after days on Cloudfront, S3 is uptodate

Tags: angular, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

Im hosting an angular 6 app on S3, everything works fine.
When updating my app on S3, I can immediate navigate to S3 over http and Im getting the newest version at once.

In addition Im hosting the app over https. Therefore Im using CloudFront.
Unfortunately it takes days til my browser shows the newest angular app over https.
One again: Over http accesing directly my S3 bucket, Im getting the newst version at once. But over https (Cloudfront) pointing to the same S3 bucket, I do not get the newest version ...

My idea was to create an invalidation on CloudFronmt for "Object Paths /index.html /assets/*", but it doesnt help.
In addition I have added a second invalidation with "Object Paths /*" but without any success.

Any ideas on that issue?

Thanks a lot
Andrej

Comment: use `/*` in your invalidation its work for me

Comment: have you tryed?

Comment: clearing cache didn't help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287328/how-to-clear-amazon-cloudfront-cache-completely

Comment: I'm wondering that my invalidating objects are all gone!
Last time I have checked them they have been there like I have described above.
Very strange thing. There isn't even a button to delete them. How can that happen?
I have added the new mentioned invalidation path /* and will see what will happen the next times